# Retrieving List<blob> cassandra example

Tags: java, list, cassandra, blob, cql3

I am trying to insert some java object as a list into cassandra.
I have a serializable java class 
I insert them as :

```
public void storeFeatures(java.util.Vector features){

        java.util.UUID uuid =   java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
        java.util.List<ByteBuffer> ls=new java.util.ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
        for(int i=0;i<features.size();i++) {
           my.package.Feature f=(my.package.Feature)features.elementAt(i);
            byte[]b=(new ObjectToBytes()).getBytes(f);
            ls.add(java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(b));
         }
        session.execute("INSERT INTO mytable ( id, features) values ( ?, ? )", uuid, ls);
    }
```

But, somehow I can not retrieve them with

```
public java.util.List getFeatures(){

        java.util.List<ByteBuffer> ret=null;
        ResultSet rows = session.execute("SELECT * FROM imgs limit 10");
        for(Row row: rows){            
            row.getBytes("features");
            ret=row.getList("features",java.nio.ByteBuffer.class);

        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I get

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Column features is of type list<blob>
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnDefinitions.checkType(ColumnDefinitions.java:291)
```

How can I retrieve list < blob > types as list < ByteBuffer >?

Comment: Why do you call ``row.getBytes("features");`` before ``getList``?

Comment: Mikhail, You saved my day with your question..Yes.. That line was the problem. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To leave an answer: there was unnecessary call to `row.getBytes("features");` which caused the error